# How to know my RAID controller card and Host Bus Adapter's BIOS and Firmware version?

Tags: linux, centos

I use

RAID: Broadcom MegaRAID SAS 9380-8e

HBA: Broadcom SAS 9300-8e

Main Board:Intel S2600IP

to connect a JBOD server.

The O.S. is CentOS Linux 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64

I was wondering that how to get my RAID card and HBA's BIOS version and FW version in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use LSI's `storcli` to query the adapter, e.g.

```
storcli /c0 show
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!